# JavaFX TreeTableView bigger show/hide columns button

Tags: javafx, treetableview

Is there a way to make the Show/Hide columns [button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm#CJADCGCA) in the [TreeTableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment with the following CSS:

```css
.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button {
    -fx-font-size: 24pt ;
}


.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu {
    -fx-font-size: null;
}

.tree-table-view .column-header, 
.tree-table-view .filler, 
.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button, 
.tree-table-view:constrained-resize .filler {

    -fx-size: 3em ;

}
```